# as3: draw a stroke to a transparent image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

i am trying to replicate the photoshop's magic wand tool to a bitmap uploaded by the user.

To achieve this effect i am using threshold to select some pixels and then manipulate those pixels, even add a stroke using this technique

http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=27940.0

With the aforementioned technique i can have the stroke that i need in a bitmap object.

The problem is that the bitmap is transformed to fit in a specific area, so the final outcome is blurred or has a variable stroke size. In addition i would like to combine the magic wand tool with the polygonal lasso tool, which i have implemented with the drawing API which is using vector graphics.

I have thought that i can find the stroke pixels, then assign a point to each one of them and finally connect the points somehow.

This is where i am stuck because the points are in no obvious order so i cannot use the drawing API to just "connect the dots".

Any help or pointing to the right direction would be very helpful, 
thanx in advance

Comment: Regarding lasso, if you'd look at Photoshop closely, you'll find lasso selecting pixels rather than being something like a curve. Vector graphics makes curves which are not aligned to pixels. You can do with lasso like this: Grab lasso graphics, using `readGraphicsData` then add a `beginFill()` before applying the path to another sprite, then call `endFill()`, you'll end up with a sprite filled with color where your pixels should be. Then you draw it on a mask `BitmapData`, this will get you the set of lasso'd pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vesper, but readGraphicsData needs FP 11.6 and i cannot use it with flash cs 5.5 which i have. I will investigate further your proposal anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Then you can record the points in an alternate way, say into an array that's coherent with what you draw as a lasso, and construct the graphics path from those records.

Comment: Yes, this is what i had in mind but it is not very easy or i cannot think of a proper way to connect the points. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to use the method you mentioned to create a stroke. It can give you satisfactory results only for simple or small shapes.
Instead you can sample each neighbour of each pixel to define if it is sticking with iteresting color.

This is example pixel bender code for marking outline of transparent image(Note that this is no longer supported in newer flash players ie. it is now executed by flash vm). color is just color of outline and threshold define alpha value at which pixels will be treated as opaque.

```
evaluatePixel()
{
    float2 oc = outCoord();
    dst = sampleNearest(src,oc);

    float4 nN = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x, oc.y - 1.0));
    float4 nNE = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x + 1.0, oc.y - 1.0));
    float4 nE = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x + 1.0 , oc.y));
    float4 nSE = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x + 1.0, oc.y + 1.0));
    float4 nS = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x, oc.y + 1.0));
    float4 nSW = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x - 1.0, oc.y + 1.0));
    float4 nW = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x - 1.0, oc.y));
    float4 nNW = sampleNearest(src,float2(oc.x - 1.0, oc.y - 1.0));

    float4 av = nN + nNE + nE + nSE + nS + nSW + nW + nNW;
    av *= 0.125;
    if(dst.a <= threshold && av.a > 0.0 && av.a < 1.0) dst = color;
    else if( dst.a > 0.0) dst = body;
    else{
        dst = color;
        dst.a = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Applying this to that image:

[image]

You get this:

[image]

Becouse of alpha fade at some point you get thicker outline. You can fix it by applying another filter which will pass only pixels that are directly adjacent to opaque(red) area. Method is very similar to the one above.
After that you get one pixel thick line:

[image]

---

Now you can determine vector shape of this outline.

1. Start move in some direction until you find first white pixel and mark it as a vertex.
2. Test neighbour vertices to find if it is connected(is white).
3. If it is you move to that pixel and repeat step 2
   Additionaly if next white pixel is in different direction then last one you mark it and the last one as vertex (maintaining the order) else make it blank.

Repeat this until you get back to first vertex or current pixel have no connection.

There are some cases where you may fail to choose correct path when edge is splitted into more lines like this:

[image]

You may want to move back to position where pixel have more connection and try another path.

---

Another way to find shape from bitmap:

1. Move in some direction and when you hit edge mark vertex and move back in direction where you came from by some predefined distance.
2. Start move around the circle where your last vertex is center and distance you moved back is radius of your circle. When you hit edge mark vertex and move back in direction perpendicular to line formed from last two vertices. Repeat this step until last vertex is close enought to first vertex.

---

Second method is rather to get approximate shape depending on given distance and number of verticies you get depends on length of shape edge but you don't need to prepare bitmap in any specific way. On the other hand first method can give you very few vertices for simple sharp shapes like rectangle regardless of its size and a lot more for complex shapes.

Here are real time visualisations of this two methods.

http://audionysos.cba.pl/edges.html

http://audionysos.cba.pl/bmscaner.html

Also please understand that these are just experimental implementations of my ideas and can be improved significantly and I do not assure you that these method are the best way of solving your problem and don't have any idea of how it's done in specialistic software like photoshop since I didn't bother to even search for such informations. 
However I hope that it will be usefull to you in some way.